# ShareActionProvider - send string with link

Tags: android, android-intent, shareactionprovider

Couldn't find the answer to my problem, so here is my question:
I have an app storing debts and where i can send the debt info to anyone using ShareActionProvider in the actionbar. It all works fine, i can send a string via, let's say, whatsapp. So far, so good. I wanted to include a link to the app in the play store at the end of the message but couldn't find out how to do it.

Here the intent I'm sending via the ShareActionProvider

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, share_message);
i.setType("text/plain");
```

How can i achieve to add something like this:
Don't forget to check out [this](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just append the link to the end.

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, share_message + " https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName());
i.setType("text/plain");
```

Comment: My answer differs from the other as it is not necessary to hardcode your package name into the string. you should be able to call `getPackageName` and get the package name for the url.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is better than nothing, but what i wanted to achieve was actually to use a String holding the link. As to say the words 'click here' with the link to the play store, instead of having the written link.

Comment: ya no. you cannot send a hyperlink.

Comment: Ahaaa! So that's why I couldn't find the answer, i just can't :D too bad. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, share_message + " https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps");
i.setType("text/plain");
```

Comment: As i commented above, this is still something, but what i wanted to do was to add a String holding the link after the share_message. Something like the words 'click here' with the link inside.

Comment: Ahh, unfortunately that will depend on the individual receiving app's ability to process some form of markup